# how to subtract previous record value from the current value in the entity framework using linq

Tags: c#

i am getting cumulative values in the database table but i need incremental value in one column , so that i need to subtract from the previous record.need to subtract from kwh. KWH_I = present kwh - previous kwh. getting error -

> "ExceptionMessage": "The operation cannot be completed because the
>   DbContext has been disposed.",

view model

```
 public partial class Total_Power
    {
        public int A_id { get; set; }
        public string DeviceImei { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeviceTimeStamp { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> KWH { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> KWH_I { get; set; }

    }

code

 [HttpGet]
    [Route("Trans/TotalPowerV2/all/{imei}/{StartDate}/{EndDate}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDatewiseTotal_PowerData_v2(string imei, string StartDate, string EndDate)
    {
        DateTime sd = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
        DateTime ed = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);
        using (TransformerEntities entities = new TransformerEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var response = from locationLog in entities.Total_Power
                .Where(s => s.DeviceImei == imei && s.DeviceTimeStamp >= sd && s.DeviceTimeStamp <= ed)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.DeviceTimeStamp)
                                   // get the previous log from locationLog                       
                               let prevLog = entities.Total_Power
                                     .Where(s => s.DeviceImei == imei
                                             && s.DeviceTimeStamp >= sd
                                             && s.DeviceTimeStamp <= ed
                                             && s.DeviceTimeStamp <= locationLog.DeviceTimeStamp
                                             && s.A_id != locationLog.A_id)
                                      .OrderByDescending(s => s.DeviceTimeStamp)
                                      .FirstOrDefault()
                               orderby locationLog.DeviceTimeStamp
                               select new
                               {
                                   A_id = locationLog.A_id,
                                   DeviceImei = locationLog.DeviceImei,
                                   DeviceTimeStamp = locationLog.DeviceTimeStamp,
                                   KWH = locationLog.KWH,
                                   prevId = prevLog != null ? prevLog.A_id : -1,
                                   KWH_I = prevLog != null ? locationLog.KWH - prevLog.KWH : 0
                               };

                return Ok(response.ToList());
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("Sorry Error Found!!!");
            }
        }
    }
```

req op

```
    [
    {
        "A_id": 943137,
        "DeviceImei": "613",
        "DeviceTimeStamp": "2020-03-24T23:45:18",
        "KWH": 326003.1,
        "KWH_I": 11,
    },
    {
        "A_id": 943133,
        "DeviceImei": "613",
        "DeviceTimeStamp": "2020-03-24T23:30:18",
        "KWH": 325992.4,
        "KWH_I": 0,
          }
]
```

Comment: Might help if you tell us _which_ values you want to subtract

Comment: Do you want to get **final one value**, or **minus one values count**?

Comment: i want to subtract te previous value from the current kwh. i have added kwh_i which is not in database. kwh_i want to calculate manually.its showing total energy consumption, i want energy consuption of each interval so that i can draw a trend of energy consumption to predict at what time energy consumption is high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok normally in SQL we would use `LEAD / LAG` window functions to perform such functionality.
But because there is no easy way to use `LEAD / LAG` in Entity Framework without using a library like `MoreLinq` or `Linq2DB` I have come up with the following solution in one of my existing projects.

```
List<TestModel> logs = new List<TestModel>();
  logs.Add(new TestModel() { A_id = 1, DeviceImei = "234", DeviceTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), KWH = 50 });
  logs.Add(new TestModel() { A_id = 2, DeviceImei = "234", DeviceTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).AddSeconds(2), KWH = 50 });
  logs.Add(new TestModel() { A_id = 3, DeviceImei = "234", DeviceTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).AddSeconds(3), KWH = 650 });
  logs.Add(new TestModel() { A_id = 4, DeviceImei = "234", DeviceTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).AddSeconds(4), KWH = 90 });
  logs.Add(new TestModel() { A_id = 5, DeviceImei = "234", DeviceTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).AddSeconds(5), KWH = 20 });
  logs.Add(new TestModel() { A_id = 6, DeviceImei = "234", DeviceTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).AddSeconds(6), KWH = 50 });

string imei = "234";
DateTime sd = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);
DateTime ed = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);


var response = from locationLog in logs
                    .Where(s => s.DeviceImei == imei && s.DeviceTimeStamp >= sd && s.DeviceTimeStamp <= ed)
                    .OrderBy(t => t.DeviceTimeStamp)

             // get the previous log from locationLog                       
             let prevLog = logs
                    .Where(s => s.DeviceImei == imei
                           && s.DeviceTimeStamp >= sd
                           && s.DeviceTimeStamp <= ed
                           && s.DeviceTimeStamp <= locationLog.DeviceTimeStamp
                           && s.A_id != locationLog.A_id)
                    .OrderByDescending(s => s.DeviceTimeStamp)
                    .FirstOrDefault()

        orderby locationLog.DeviceTimeStamp
                           select new
                           {
                               A_id = locationLog.A_id,
                               DeviceImei = locationLog.DeviceImei,
                               DeviceTimeStamp = locationLog.DeviceTimeStamp,
                               KWH = locationLog.KWH,
                               prevId = prevLog != null ? prevLog.A_id : -1,
                               KWH_I = prevLog != null ? locationLog.KWH - prevLog.KWH : 0
                           };
```

When translated to SQL this would translate to an `OUTER APPLY` SQL query.

Comment: will it not effect the performance ? cant we store in variable simply and substract it. anyway i will try ur solution and let u know.

Comment: Depends on you indexes in the database. I have a table with Millions of records and the query has no performance issue on it. I have an index on my `DeviceTimeStamp` and `DeviceTimeStamp ` columns

Comment: storing it in variable and performing a for / foreach loop operation might not have a performance impact on less data, but for large datasets you will notice that performing such operations on the DB server will be alot better - if you have the correct indexes

Comment: "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.",im getting this error. what could be the problem?

Comment: @krishnamohan `response` is `IQueryable` on this line `return Ok(response)` you must materialise the list by calling either `response.AsEnumerable()` or `response.ToList()`

Comment: i did not understand what is "prevId": 943125, in the response. is it required. can u tell about this prevId purpose

Comment: @krishnamohan no it is not required you can remove that. That is just for debugging purpose